# How to do something only on odd indexes in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, indexing

I'm start learning haskell now but I've a case where I couldn't find the solution to solve it

**Case**:
`list = [4, 9, 2, 4, 2]`

**Wanna become**:
`list = [4, 18, 2, 8, 2]`

It's like multiplying 2 only on odd indexes, can we do this in Haskell?

Comment: Yes you can. Have you try writing a recursive function that does that? What would it do to the empty list? What would it do with a list of one element? What would it do with a list of two elements or more?

Answer (score 7):

You can make an infinite list that interleaves `id` and `(2*)` with `cycle [id, (2*)]`, then we apply these functions to the elements by using [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith):

```
zipWith ($) (cycle [id, (2*)]) [4, 9, 2, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define this function recursively. Just consider what would be the result of calling it on an empty list, a list with one element, a list with two elements or more.

```hs
map_odd :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
map_odd f [] = []
map_odd f [x] = [x]
map_odd f (a:b:l) = a : f b : map_odd f l
```

Note how function `f` needs to have type `a -> a`, not a generic `a -> b`, because it's only applied to some elements in the list.